# Error al adaptar un codigo de matlab a python: Unexpected EOF while parsing

Tags: python, matlab

necesito adaptar el siguiente codigo de matlab a python:

```
%Holms case properties
E=120.66e9; %Young modulus, E=120.66GPa
alpha=14.4e-6; %Expansion coef, Alpha=10e-6 mm-1K-1
v=0.3; %Poisson modulus
a=101.6/1000; %Tube inner radius 101.6 mm
b=304.8/1000; %Tube outer radius 304.8 mm

%Calculation of internal and external temperature profiles
r=[a:(b-a)/19:b]; %20 divisions in radial coordinate
Theta=[0:360/71:360]; %72 divisions in circunferential coordinates
Theta=Theta*pi/180; %Angle in radians
T=zeros([size(Theta,2),size(r,2)]); %Temperature array, rows angle variation, column radial variation
for i=1:size(r,2) %To create temperature distribution (See Logie et al. Eq. 53)
    for i2=1:size(Theta,2)
        T(i2,i)=((555.56*b)/(b^2-a^2))*((r(i)^2-a^2)/r(i))*cos(Theta(i2))+277.78*(1-log(b/r(i))/log(b/a))+273.15;
    end
end
Tint=T(:,1);
Text=T(:,size(r,2));
%Fourier fitting
Tm_o=550.9;
B1_o=555.6;
Tm_i=273.15;
B1_i=0;

%Stress calculation
K=(Tm_i-Tm_o)/log(b/a);
for i=1:size(r,2)
    for i2=1:size(Theta,2)
        K_theta(i2,i)=(r(i)*a*b)/(b^2-a^2)*(((B1_i*b-B1_o*a)/(a^2+b^2))*cos(Theta(i2)));
        T_theta(i2,i)=T(i2,i)-(Tm_i-Tm_o)*log(b/r(i))/log(b/a)-Tm_o;
        sigma_r(i2,i)=(K*alpha*E/(2*(1-v)))*(-log(b/r(i))-(a^2/(b^2-a^2))*(1-b^2/r(i)^2)*log(b/a))+K_theta(i2,i)*((alpha*E)/(2*(1-v)))*(1-a^2/r(i)^2)*(1-b^2/r(i)^2);
        sigma_theta(i2,i)=(K*alpha*E/(2*(1-v)))*(1-log(b/r(i))-(a^2/(b^2-a^2))*(1+b^2/r(i)^2)*log(b/a))+K_theta(i2,i)*(alpha*E/(2*(1-v)))*(3-(a^2+b^2)/r(i)^2-a^2*b^2/r(i)^4);
        sigma_z(i2,i)=(K*alpha*E/(2*(1-v)))*(1-2*log(b/r(i))-((2*a^2)/(b^2-a^2))*log(b/a))+(K_theta(i2,i)*alpha*E*v/(1-v))*(2-(a^2+b^2)/r(i)^2)-alpha*E*T_theta(i2,i);
        sigma_eq(i2,i)=sqrt(((sigma_r(i2,i)-sigma_theta(i2,i))^2+(sigma_theta(i2,i)-sigma_z(i2,i))^2+(sigma_z(i2,i)-sigma_r(i2,i))^2)/2);
    end
end
```

Hasta ahora, mi codigo de python es:

```
import math
from math import pi,cos,sqrt,log
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
#Holms case properties
E=120.66e9     ##Young modulus E=120.66GPa
alpha=14.4e-6 ##Expansion coef, Alpha=10e-6 mm-1K-1
v=0.3 ##Poisson modulus
a=101.6/1000 ##Tube inner radius 101.6 mm
b=304.8/1000 ##Tube outer radius 304.8 mm
c=20
w=(b-a)/c
z=72
ang=360/z

##Calculation of internal and external temperature profiles
r=[] 
Theta=[]
index=0
for i in range(c):
    r.append(index)
    r[index]=a+index*w
    index=index+1
index=0
for i in range(0,73):
    Theta.append(index)
    Theta[index]=i*ang
    Theta[index]=Theta[index]*pi/180
    
w=len(r)
h=len(Theta)
 ##Angle in radians
T=np.zeros((w, h))##Temperature array, rows angle variation, column radial variation
for i in range(w):
    ##To create temperature distribution ##(See Logie et al. Eq. 53)
    for i2 in range(h):
        T[i][i2] = ((555.56 * b) / (b ** 2 - a ** 2)) * ((r[i] ** 2 - a ** 2) / r[i]) * cos(Theta[i2]) + 277.78 * (1 - log(b / r[i]) / log(b / a)) + 273.15
Tint=T[:,1]
Text=T[:,w]
##Fourier fitting
Tm_o=550.9
B1_o=555.6
Tm_i=273.15
B1_i=0
K_theta=[[],[]]
T_theta=[[],[]]
sigma_r=[[],[]]
sigma_theta=[[],[]]
sigma_z=[[],[]]
sigma_eq=[[],[]]

##Stress calculation
K=(Tm_i-Tm_o)/log(b/a)
for i in range (w):
    for i2 in range (h):
        K_theta[i2][i] = (r[i]*a*b)/(b**2-a**2)*(((B1_i*b-B1_o*a)/(a**2+b**2))*cos(Theta[i2]))
        T_theta[i2][i]=T[i2][i]-(Tm_i-Tm_o)*log(b/r[i])/log(b/a)-Tm_o
        sigma_r[i2][i]=(K*alpha*E/(2*(1-v)))*(-log(b/r[i])-(a**2/(b**2-a**2))*(1-b**2/r[i]**2)*log(b/a))+K_theta[i2][i]*((alpha*E)/(2*(1-v)))*(1-a**2/r[i]**2)*(1-b**2/r[i]**2)
        sigma_theta[i2][i]=(K*alpha*E/(2*(1-v)))*(1-log(b/r[i])-(a**2/(b**2-a**2))*(1+b**2/r[i]**2)*log(b/a))+K_theta[i2][i]*(alpha*E/(2*(1-v)))*(3-(a**2+b**2)/r[i]**2-a**2*b**2/r[i]**4)
        sigma_z[i2][i]=(K*alpha*E/(2*(1-v)))*(1-2*log(b/r[i])-((2*a**2)/(b**2-a**2))*log(b/a))+(K_theta[i2][i]*alpha*E*v/(1-v))*(2-(a**2+b**2)/r[i]**2)-alpha*E*T_theta[i2][i]
        sigma_eq[i2][i]=sqrt(((sigma_r[i2][i]-sigma_theta([i2][i])**2+(sigma_theta[i2][i]-sigma_z[i2][i])**2+(sigma_z[i2][i]-sigma_r[i2][i])**2)/2)
```

Al compilar, me salta el error unexpected EOF while parsing al final del todo  y no sé porque. Alguien sabe porque me sale este error?

Comment: Que tratas de hacer? Lo más probable es que haya un modulo de python que te simplifique las cosas. Recuerda que en python se opta por la simplicidad y estilo pythonico

Answer (score 0):

Tienes errores de sintaxis y además estás creando los vectores con la longitud incorrecta.

Te adjunto tu código con las correcciones correspondientes:

```
from math import pi, cos, sqrt, log
import numpy as np

E = 120.66e9;
alpha = 14.4e-6;
v = 0.3;
a = 101.6 / 1000;
b = 304.8 / 1000;

##Calculation of internal and external temperature profiles
r = np.arange(a, b + (b - a) / 20, (b - a) / 19)
Theta = np.arange(0, 360 + 360 / 71, 360 / 71)
Theta = Theta * pi / 180

T = np.zeros([len(Theta), len(r)])

for i in range(len(Theta)):
    for j in range(len(r)):
        T[i][j] = ((555.56 * b) / (b ** 2 - a ** 2)) * ((r[j] ** 2 - a ** 2) / r[j]) * cos(Theta[i]) + 277.78 * (
                1 - log(b / r[j]) / log(b / a)) + 273.15

Tint = T[:, 0]
Text = T[:, np.size(r) - 1]

Tm_o = 550.9
B1_o = 555.6
Tm_i = 273.15
B1_i = 0

K = (Tm_i - Tm_o) / log(b / a)

K_theta = np.zeros([len(Theta), len(r)])
T_theta = np.zeros([len(Theta), len(r)])
sigma_r = np.zeros([len(Theta), len(r)])
sigma_theta = np.zeros([len(Theta), len(r)])
sigma_z = np.zeros([len(Theta), len(r)])
sigma_eq = np.zeros([len(Theta), len(r)])
for i in range(np.size(r)):
    for j in range(np.size(Theta)):
        K_theta[j][i] = (r[i] * a * b) / (b ** 2 - a ** 2) * (((B1_i * b - B1_o * a) / (a ** 2 + b ** 2)) * cos(Theta[j]))
        T_theta[j][i] = T[j][i] - (Tm_i - Tm_o) * log(b / r[i]) / log(b / a) - Tm_o
        sigma_r[j][i] = (K * alpha * E / (2 * (1 - v))) * (-log(b / r[i]) - (a ** 2 / (b ** 2 - a ** 2)) * (1 -b ** 2 / r[i] ** 2) * log(b / a)) + K_theta[j][i] * ((alpha * E) / (2 * (1 - v))) * (1 - a ** 2 / r[i] ** 2) * (1 - b ** 2 / r[i] ** 2)
        sigma_theta[j][i] = (K * alpha * E / (2 * (1 - v))) * (1 - log(b / r[i]) - (a ** 2 / (b ** 2 - a ** 2)) *(1 + b ** 2 / r[i] ** 2) * log(b / a)) + K_theta[j][i] * (alpha * E / (2 * (1 - v))) * (3 - (a ** 2 + b ** 2) / r[i] ** 2 - a ** 2 * b ** 2 / r[i] ** 4)
        sigma_z[j][i]= (K * alpha * E / (2 * (1 - v))) * (1 - 2 * log(b / r[i]) - ((2 * a ** 2) / (b ** 2 - a ** 2)) * log(b / a)) + (K_theta[j][i] * alpha * E * v / (1 - v)) * (2 - (a ** 2 + b ** 2) / r[i] ** 2) - alpha * E * T_theta[j][i]
        sigma_eq[j][i] = sqrt(((sigma_r[j][i] - sigma_theta[j][i]) ** 2 + (sigma_theta[j][i] - sigma_z[j][i]) ** 2 + (sigma_z[j][i] - sigma_r[j][i]) ** 2) / 2)
```